# 32-bit and 64-bit setup projects

Tags: sql-server, winforms, setup-project

How to create a single setup file which target both 32 and 64 bit system? It has dependencies on .net framework and third party dll. Also when the application run for first time there is a database installation procedure which install 32 bit sqlexpress. another problem is how to get existing(already installed)  sql server intance both 64 and 32 bit and select it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with WIX

http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-target-32bit-and-64bit-a-net-applications-with-wix-and-separate-msi-packages/

Comment: do i need to install wix package

Answer (score 1):

You can use WIX.

See
[Example WiX-based setup that can be used to build both 32-bit and 64-bit MSIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/08/09/4317654.aspx)